# How to find the Eigenfunction of the given Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a difficulty in solving this problem:

Find the eigenfunction of the operator $T$, such that $$  Tf(x,p(x),q(x))=f_{xp}-f_{xqx}, $$
where $p,q$ are continuous map.

I tried to solve it,but I didn't succeed. 
(sorry me for the bad english)

Comment: there is a lot of information missing here

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what is $f_{xp}$? on which spaces does $T$ operate? etc.
also, what have you tried?

Comment: $f_{x,p}=\partial_{p}{\partial_{x}f}$,T operate on $L^p(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: I tried to solve it,trying to solve this PDE$Tf=f$

Comment: So the problem is to solve $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial p}-\frac{\partial ^3f}{\partial x^2\partial q}=\lambda f$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ and a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Is this right? @mklplo

Comment: yes,with $p(x),q(x)$  continuous map

Comment: $f(x,p,q)=e^{x+p+q}$ is an eigenfunction to the eigenvalue $0$.@mklplo

Comment: thanks,but I forgot that $\lambda\not=0$

Comment: OK $f(x,p,q)=e^{ax+bp+cq}$ is an eigenfunction to the eigenvalue $\lambda=ab-a^2c$@mklplo

Comment: So for example $f(x,p,q)=e^{x+p}$  satisfies $Tf=f$

Comment: but if I take the case of the example i get that:$\partial_p(e^{x+p}(p_{x}+1))=e^{x+p}$,that is false

Comment: As I think I have written badly the exercise, I rewrite it:"Find the eigenfunction of operator T,such that,$ Tf(x,p(x),p'(x))=\partial_p(\partial_xf)-\partial_x(\partial_{p'}(\partial_x f)) $,with $f\in L^p(R ^3)$,$p\in C^1([a,b])$,with the eigenvalue $\lambda \not =0$,and $ f\not=0\wedge f\not=c$where c is a real number"

Comment: As I think it is not quite clear in Your question if You apply $T$ to the function $x\mapsto f(x,p(x),p'(x))$ or to a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Shouldn´t $x,p,q$ be treated as independent variables for the expressions $f_{xp}$ and $f_{xqx}$ to make sense?

Comment: The variable p and q depend on x,and q are the first derivative of p.

Comment: what is then e.g. $x\partial p$ ??

Comment: $\partial_p(\partial_xf)=f_{px}$,and $\partial_x(\partial_{p'}(\partial_xf))=f_{xp'x}$

Comment: ok, this doesn´t answer my question. The expressions make only sense to me if You treat them as independant variables.

Comment: in realty f is a functional and not a function,$\partial_{x}f$ is the Lagrangian and $Tf$ is the first member of Euler-Lagrange Equation.

Comment: I did some calculations and I find the seguent pde:$p'\partial_p^2f-p'\partial_{pp'}f-\partial_pf-p''\partial_{pp'}f=f$,that I have riwritten,this pde(with $p'=q$ and $p''=t$): $q\partial_p^2f-q\partial_{pq}f-\partial_pf-t\partial_{pq}f=f$(If my reasoning is correct the last equation,is a common pde,where the variables are independent).